# Copy the month name, not number into a variable vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get the name of the month to compare if it is the current month. What is in the cell I'm looking at is usually something like this:

```
=Today()
```

or

```
10/24/2013
```

I've tried copy and paste to get the names instead of the numbers, but it doesn't do it. I'm sure there is a way to get the month name from the value in the cell, I just don't know what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have

=TODAY()

in a cell (say G19), format that cell as "mmmm"

Then in VBA:

```
Sub Getmonth()
    MsgBox Range("G19").Text
End Sub
```

Comment: Sweet that did it. I never thought to use `.text` to get the value. Thanks!